# Compiler Internal error

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe6

I am experiencing compiler internal error on Delphi XE6. I don't know what it means. I always have to Clean, Compile and then build to get rid of it. This is actuall workaround. It's fine but annoying. If I click on it it takes me into the last line in Lan.Graph.pas unit. (end.) How can I find out what is a problem?

Thanks for your help.

[image: Internal error]

Comment: Are you using Firemonkey? If so, what platform(s)? I would also think it's 10 times easier to copy/paste that error than to take a screenshot.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Resolving_Internal_Errors_%28Delphi%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler reports an internal error, that is a compiler bug. The only thing you can do is to report it to Embarcadero: http://quality.embarcadero.com/